# Wordpress theme.json

Tags: json, wordpress, colors

I am working with Wordpress 6.3. I have a custom theme and currently editing the theme.json file.
Right now, i am trying to disable the custom colors within the color palette. I have the following code for this:
[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MuF6P.png)

The problem that i got is that the custom colors are still visble within Wordpress. I want to be sure that customers only have access to the color palette that has been made by us.
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KdCKa.png)

Does anyone have an idea on how i can disable the custom colors?